# SQL to determine minimum sequential days when value delta was hit

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following table contains one record per `id` with the `value`, it has several hundreds of records:

```
 id  | value  
-----+------------
   1 | 118.89
   2 | 113.90
   3 | 110.62
   4 | 105.37
   5 | 119.16
   6 | 118.33
   7 | 116.93
   8 | 117.74
   9 | 118.01
  10 | 125.00
  11 | 130.62
  12 | 137.50
  13 | 136.65
  14 | 133.80
  15 | 132.53
  16 | 133.03
  17 | 131.91
  18 | 134.06
  19 | 131.03
  20 | 132.38
```

I am looking for a SQL query on this table with good performance that gives me the rows for the minimum amount of consecutive `id`s when the `value` changed by `n` (floating point number), to any side(+ or -).

For example, if `n=13.5`, then the rows with `id` 4,5 should be shown, if `n=19.2`, then rows with `id` 9-12 should be shown.

Comment: @SalmanA if I understand the question correctly, he is looking for the smallest set of consecutive rows where the cumulative delta is over the threshold. The difference between the value 118.01 of row 9 and the 137.5 of row 12, is the smallest set of consecutive rows for which the cumulative delta is ≥ 19.2. Your suggested solution only looks for delta between 2 neighboring rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and thanks for sharing this very interesting challenge.
Next time, it would be very helpful if you could provide:
Full DDL, Actual INSERT statements for the sample data, The desired result set in detail, and a somewhat more verbose explanation.
A few people posted answers and deleted them when they realized they misunderstood the question.

I wrote down the DDL and inserts:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO 
(ID INT PRIMARY KEY, Value DECIMAL(5,2));

INSERT INTO FOO (ID, Value)
VALUES  (  1 , 118.89 ),
         (  2 , 113.90 ),
         (  3 , 110.62 ),
         (  4 , 105.37 ),
         (  5 , 119.16 ),
         (  6 , 118.33 ),
         (  7 , 116.93 ),
         (  8 , 117.74 ),
         (  9 , 118.01 ),
         ( 10 , 125.00 ),
         ( 11 , 130.62 ),
         ( 12 , 137.50 ),
         ( 13 , 136.65 ),
         ( 14 , 133.80 ),
         ( 15 , 132.53 ),
         ( 16 , 133.03 ),
         ( 17 , 131.91 ),
         ( 18 , 134.06 ),
         ( 19 , 131.03 ),
         ( 20 , 132.38 );

SELECT  * 
FROM    FOO;
```

I hope that I understand your question correctly, so here is my solution approach.

Before getting to the actual SQL solution, I tried to realize the mathematical complexity.
Let's assume that we have 10 rows in the table.
The number of different sequential groups is a divergent series of natural numbers, or a triangular number.
It starts with 1 option for a group of 10 sequential rows from 1-10.
then we have 2 options for any group of 9 sequential rows, 1-9 and 2-10.
Then 3 for any group of 8 rows etc.
The total number of sequential groups at any length can be easily caluclated.
If it were a full traingular number, the forumula would be n(n+1)/2.
Here, since the smallest group consists of 2 rows, and not 1, it comes up to (n-1)(n-1+1)/2 = n(n-1)/2.

I will be using SQL Server syntax for this, as I don't like using PL/pgSQL, and don't have much experience with it.
Someone with more experience in PL/pgSQL is welcome to convert it, shouldn't be too hard.
I never understood why so many RDBMS don't allow combining imperative constructs with SQL on the same script scope.

My first thought was to try a naive, set based approach to calculate all possible groups using a recursive query, 
with varying group sizes for the OVER clause.
For 500 rows we would need to compute the total deltas for 500*499/2 groups = ~125K.
It would have been nice if we could do something like:

```
DECLARE @MaxGroupSize INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Foo);
DECLARE @Threshold DECIMAL(5,2) = 13.5;
WITH GroupDeltas
AS
(
SELECT  1 AS GroupSize, 
        ID,
        CAST((  LEAD(Value) 
                OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC) - Value) 
        AS DECIMAL(38,2)) AS GroupDelta
FROM    Foo
UNION ALL
SELECT  (GroupSize + 1),
        ID,
        SUM(GroupDelta) 
            OVER (  ORDER BY ID ASC 
                    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 0 /*NO GO WITH (GroupSize - 2)*/  FOLLOWING)
FROM    GroupDeltas
WHERE   (GroupSize + 1) <= @MaxGroupSize
)
SELECT  * 
FROM    GroupDeltas
WHERE   ABS(GroupDelta) >= @Threshold
        AND
        GroupSize = (
                        SELECT  MIN(GroupSize) 
                        FROM    GroupDeltas 
                        WHERE   GroupSize > 1 -- Eliminate Anchor
                                AND
                                ABS(GroupDelta) >= @Threshold   
                    );
```

but unfortunately, the frame offset must use a constant expression.
No variables nor column expressions are allowed.
Note that the query above works for the first example with the group size of 2, 
but only because I used a literal 0 offset instead of the required (GroupSize - 2) which is not allowed...

It also would have been nice if we could add a stop condition to the recursive member

```
 AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT  NULL
                    FROM    GroupDeltas
                    WHERE   ABS(GroupDelta) >= 13.5
                )
```

But we can only refernece the CTE in the recursive member once...
Anyway, this approach doesn't work to begin with, so I didn't test it any further.
I only added it here as an interesting mental exercise I went through.

That leaves us with an iterative approach.
Since you also asked for a 'good performing' query,
I figured we can get away without calculating all possible groups.

My idea was to create a loop that starts with the smallest possible group size, 
and stop when we hit a match. 
I didn't want to use a RBAR cursor, so I opted for the more efficient window function, 
using dynamic execution to circumvent the offset constant limitation.
Following is my attempt.
Note that if there are more than 1 groups that satisfy the threshold, both will be shown.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #GroupDeltas;
GO

DECLARE @Threshold DECIMAL(5,2) = 19.2,
        @MaxGroupSize INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FOO),
        @GroupSize INT = 2, -- Initial Group Size
        @SQL VARCHAR(1000);

CREATE TABLE #GroupDeltas 
    (
        StartID INT, 
        GroupSize INT,
        GroupDelta DECIMAL(9,2),
        PRIMARY KEY (StartID, GroupSize)
    );

WHILE @GroupSize <= @MaxGroupSize
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = '
                ;WITH DeltasFromNext
                AS
                    (
                        SELECT  ID,
                                LEAD(Value) OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC) - Value AS Delta
                        FROM    FOO
                    )
                    SELECT  ID, 
                            ' + CAST(@GroupSize AS VARCHAR(5)) +',
                            SUM(Delta) 
                            OVER (  ORDER BY ID 
                                    ROWS BETWEEN 
                                    CURRENT ROW AND 
                                    ' + CAST(@GroupSize - 2 AS VARCHAR(5)) 
                                    + ' FOLLOWING)
                    FROM DeltasFromNext;
    '
    INSERT INTO #GroupDeltas
    EXECUTE (@SQL);
    IF EXISTS   (
                    SELECT  NULL
                    FROM    #GroupDeltas
                    WHERE   ABS(GroupDelta) >= @Threshold
                )
    BREAK;
    SET @GroupSize += 1
END
SELECT  * 
FROM    #GroupDeltas
WHERE   ABS(GroupDelta) >= @Threshold
ORDER BY GroupSize, StartID;
```

### HTH

PS: 
Feedback and improvement suggestions are very welcome. I find this to be a very interesting exercise and there are probably better ways to achieve it... 
I may revisit it again if I have some time to spare.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that `id` has no gaps, you can implement this using:

```
select id, (next_id - id + 1) as cnt
from (select t.*,
             (select min(t2.id)
              from t t2
              where t2.id > t.id and
                    t2.value > t.value + 13.5
             ) as next_id
      from t
     ) t
order by cnt asc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

It is not obvious to me how you can use window functions for this.